# How to pass the another variable to the Highchart basic line which should be dynamic

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, highcharts

I am trying to do the basic line highcharts to be dynamic and i have done dynamic and now the requirement i would like to pass the another variable to the X-axis variable with other column, this is my code which is in PHP script :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>RNA</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="regression.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="highcharts.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {


 var sourceData = [ 

                    <?php

                        if (($handle = fopen("data.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {

                            $i=0;

                            $len = count(file('data.csv'));

                            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

                                    if($i==$len - 1){

                                        echo "{y: ".$i.",".$data[1].", extprop: '".$data[4]."'}";

                                        }else{

                                        echo "{y: ".$i.",".$data[1].", extprop: '".$data[4]."'}," ;

                                        }

                                $i++;
                            }
                                fclose($handle);
                            }
                ?>

                ];

        $('#container').highcharts({
            title: {
                text: 'RNA - CP ( Radio Network Availability - Customer Perceived)',
                x: -20 //center
            },

        tooltip: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        console.log(this.point.extprop);
                        var s = 'The value for <b>' + this.x +
                            '</b> is <b>' + this.y + '</b>';
                        if (this.point.extprop) {
                           s += 'for <b>' + this.point.extprop + '</b>';
                        }
                        return s;
                    }
                },


            subtitle: {
                text: '',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: [

            <?php   
                 if (($handle = fopen("data.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
            $i=0;

            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

                        if($i==$len - 1){

                                echo "'".$data[0]."'" ;

                        }else{
                                echo "'".$data[0]."'," ;
                        }

                $i++;
            }
                fclose($handle);
            }

            ?>  

            ]},
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Percent'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: '%'
            },

            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                //align: 'right',
                //verticalAlign: 'middle',
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'RNA',
                data: sourceData
            },
            {
                type: 'line',
                marker: { enabled: false },
                /* function returns data for trend-line */
                data: (function() {
                  return fitData(sourceData).data;
                })()
            }],
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            }
      });
});

        </script>
        </head>

<body>

<script src="exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

this is the csv file :

```
 17-Jul-14  99.43   99.69   99.86   power issue
    18-Jul-14   99.4    99.64   99.83   flood
    19-Jul-14   99.24   99.63   99.82   power issue
    20-Jul-14   99.4    99.67   99.85   flood
    21-Jul-14   99.21   99.65   99.82   power issue
    22-Jul-14   98.45   99.35   99.53   flood
    23-Jul-14   98.41   99.39   99.56   power issue
    24-Jul-14   99.18   99.6    99.79   flood
    25-Jul-14   99.36   99.66   99.87   power issue
    26-Jul-14   99.31   99.67   99.89   flood
    27-Jul-14   99.38   99.64   99.89   power issue
    28-Jul-14   99.2    99.57   99.76   flood
    29-Jul-14   99.38   99.64   99.84   power issue
    30-Jul-14   99.32   99.63   99.82   flood
    31-Jul-14   99.24   99.61   99.8    power issue
    1-Aug-14    99.38   99.65   99.84   flood
```

Error : when i inspect element at line no : 20

```
var sourceData = [ 

                {x: 0,y: 0,99.43, extprop: 'power issue'},{x: 1,y: 1,99.40, extprop: 'flood'},{x: 2,y: 2,99.24, extprop: 'power issue'},{x: 3,y: 3,99.40, extprop: 'flood'},{x: 4,y: 4,99.21, extprop: 'power issue'},{x: 5,y: 5,98.45, extprop: 'flood'},{x: 6,y: 6,98.41, extprop: 'power issue'},{x: 7,y: 7,99.18, extprop: 'flood'},{x: 8,y: 8,99.36, extprop: 'power issue'},{x: 9,y: 9,99.31, extprop: 'flood'},{x: 10,y: 10,99.38, extprop: 'power issue'},{x: 11,y: 11,99.20, extprop: 'flood'},{x: 12,y: 12,99.38, extprop: 'power issue'},{x: 13,y: 13,99.32, extprop: 'flood'} ];                    ];
```

And this is graph without mouse over : http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data

In the pop up when mouse over the date and value is coming according to this the graph is plotting and now i want to add the reason for the pop up that is coming i have passed the value in source code loop like this :

```
var sourceData = [ 
                <?php
                            if (($handle = fopen("data.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
                                $i=0;
                                $len = count(file('data.csv'));
                                while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                                        if($i==$len - 1){
                                            echo "[".$i.",".$data[1].",".$data[4]."]";
                                            }else{
                                            echo "[".$i.",".$data[1].",".$data[4]."]," ;
                                            }
                                    $i++;
                                }
                                    fclose($handle);
                                }
                    ?>

                ];
```

But the problem i am getting when i am Inspect element : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

And regression.js file get from the Github : https://github.com/Tom-Alexander/regression-js

And This is screen shot : please observe in the pop up , when mouse over :

[image]

When mouse over the pop up is coming on the particular point on the graph and now i want to pass the 4th column to the mouse over pop up with 4th column , i have tried in the above source code passed the 4th column but i got the error ; i know it will not generate the graph but the reason has to pass must to, in which date what is the issue is ...

please help ,
thanks.

This is output i want to pass the 4th column in the tool tip please observe :

[image]

In the above diagram the tool tip has the reason , this the reason the 4th column has to come ..please help

Comment: You can also skip php script and load your CSV by $.get() function in the javascript. See the [example](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/preprocessing-data-from-a-file-csv-xml-json)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a custom property to your data to have it show in the tooltip you need to add to your  `sourceData` array. Psuedo code below:

```
var sourceData = [ 
                <?php
                            if (($handle = fopen("data.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
                                $i=0;
                                $len = count(file('data.csv'));
                                while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                                        if($i==$len - 1){
                                            echo "{x: ".$i.", y: ".$data[1].", extprop: '".$data[4]."'}";
                                            }else{
                                            echo "{x: ".$i.", y: ".$data[1].", extprop: '".$data[4]."'}," ;
                                            }
                                    $i++;
                                }
                                    fclose($handle);
                                }
                    ?>

                ];
```

You need to change the [point object](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data) to the `{...}` format instead of `[...]`. Where `y` is the yValue and `extprop` is some extended info you want (this property name can be any non-reserved name).

Then in your tooltip you need to add this extprop:

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function () {
        console.log(this.point.extprop);
        var s = 'The value for <b>' + this.x +
            '</b> is <b>' + this.y + '</b>';
        if (this.point.extprop) {
           s += 'for <b>' + this.point.extprop + '</b>';
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, i am passing the 3 points but i want the 4th column in the tool tip when mouse over. ..please observe the graph

Comment: yes the revised i tested but the error i got in the above comment ....configuring the tooltip with extra column ....?

Comment: You tried with `echo "{x: ".$i.", y: ".$data[1].", extprop: '".$data[4]."'}";`? What does your `sourceData` look like?

Comment: You still did not add the fix: `echo "{x: ".$i.", y: ".$data[1].", extprop: '".$data[4]."'}";`

Comment: It looks to me like you are adding some extra characters to the end of the sourceData string: `];                    `. You just need one closing `];` instead you have 2.

Comment: yes added , and by initial in the tool tip the data is coming that i have done date and percentage added by initial and i am trying to put the 4th column in the tool tip as the dynamic according to the dates with x and y axis...?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean with that. Did you modify your `tooltip`? Did you remove the extraneous `];`?

Comment: WAIT I HAVE PAINTED THE GRAPH I WILL ATTACH THE SNAPSHOT , PLEASE SEE ...I HAVE EDITED THE CODE ..

Comment: the extra ]; is not an error ..please see the updated graph ...adding the extra column in the tool tip

Comment: How are you adding the the extra column to the tooltip? A picture of your chart is not helpful. Did you modify the `tooltip` code?

Comment: nope...and that is my question  i want to add the extra column in the tool tip so that when mouse over the 4th coulmn data will come according to the loop at a particular date the reason will come...

Comment: Did you read my answer? It is in there. You need to modify your tooltip.

Comment: yes i have read and i have done modify also the tool tip with date and percent is coming ...in that tooltip the how to add the extra column that is ...4th column...? in the tool tip

Comment: same values are showing in the tooltip ..i.e....date and percent in the tool tip...

Comment: In your data CSV you have `17-Jul-14  99.43   99.69   99.86   power issue`. Is "power issue" the 4th column or is "99.86" the 4th column? The use of `$data[4]` means you are taking "power issue" since it is 0-based. I do not understand why your chart is not showing that and is instead showing "REASON". Also it makes no sense why you data points look like `{x: 0,y: 0,99.43, extprop: 'power issue'}`. Why is there "0," before "99.43"? If possible can you paste your complet chart code that is created via your PHP - not your PHP code. Just what the chart code looks like.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60706/discussion-on-answer-by-wergeld-how-to-pass-the-another-variable-to-the-highchar).

Comment: actaully the csv will take 0,1,2,3,4 ... this is the column formate in the csv..power issue is the 4th column

Comment: {x: 0,y: 0,99.43, extprop: 'power issue'}   here 0 is the trend line passing...code that is source code ..

Comment: You cannot have 2 y values like that. That makes no sense.

Comment: Ok, the comments are getting out of hand here - please take it to the chatroom that I created for you [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60706/discussion-on-answer-by-wergeld-how-to-pass-the-another-variable-to-the-highchar)

Comment: means ,..the trend line should be there...and the extra column to be added...please observe the updated snapshot which i added the reason in tool tip in paint

Comment: @bluefeet, Woops. Missed that.

Comment: @John the link is in my comment http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60706/discussion-on-answer-by-wergeld-how-to-pass-the-another-variable-to-the-highchar

Comment: Hi, @wergeld.......please suggest how to pass the dates instead of values i.e..18-Jul-14', '19-Jul-14', '20-Jul-14....