# How to change the point color to red that is lowest point plotted in the graph and 2nd issue is animation effect is not supporting in the ie10,ie8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, highcharts

i am working on the high charts to make the dynamic and this is the graph :

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
            <title>RNA</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="regression.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(function () {
        var sourceData = [
              [0, 99.43], [1, 99.40],
              [2, 99.24], [3, 99.40],
              [4, 99.21], [5, 99.45],
              [6, 99.41], [7, 99.18],
              [8, 99.36], [9, 99.31],
              [10, 99.38], [11, 99.20],
            [12, 99.38], [13, 99.32]
          ];
    $('#container').highcharts({
              title: {
                  text: 'RNA - CP ( Radio Network Availability - Customer Perceived)',
                  x: -20 //center
              },
              tooltip: {
                  formatter: function () {

                          if(this.series.name == 'Series 2'){
                          return false ;
                      }
                      //console.log(this.point.extprop);
                      var s = 'The value for <b>' + this.x +
                          '</b> is <b>' + this.y + '</b>';
                      if (this.point.extprop) {
                          s += 'for <b>' + this.point.extprop + '</b>';
                      }
                      return s;
                  }
              },
              subtitle: {
                  text: '',
                  x: -20
              },
              xAxis: {
                  categories: ['18-Jul-14', '19-Jul-14', '20-Jul-14', '18-Jul-14', '19-Jul-14', '20-Jul-14', '18-Jul-14', '19-Jul-14', '20-Jul-14', '18-Jul-14', '19-Jul-14', '20-Jul-14', '19-Jul-14', '20-Jul-14', '20-Jul-14'],
                  labels:{rotation: 40, x:-20}
              },
              yAxis: {
                  title: {
                      text: 'Percent'
                  },
                  plotLines: [{
                      value: 0,
                      width: 1,
                      color: '#808080'
                  }]
              },
              legend: {
                  layout: 'vertical',
                  //align: 'right',
                  //verticalAlign: 'middle',
                  borderWidth: 0
              },
              series: [{
                  name: 'RNA',
                  data: [{
                      x: 0,
                      y: 99.43,
                      extprop: 'power issue'
                  }, {
                      x: 1,
                      y: 99.40,
                      extprop: 'flood'
                  }, {
                      x: 2,
                      y: 99.24,
                      extprop: 'power issue'
                  }, {
                      x: 3,
                      y: 99.40,
                      extprop: 'flood'
                  }, {
                      x: 4,
                      y: 99.21,
                      extprop: 'power issue'
                  }, {
                      x: 5,
                      y: 98.45,
                      extprop: 'flood'
                  }, {
                      x: 6,
                      y: 98.41,
                      extprop: 'power issue'
                  }, {
                      x: 7,
                      y: 99.18,
                      extprop: 'flood'
                  }, {
                      x: 8,
                      y: 99.36,
                      extprop: 'power issue'
                  }, {
                      x: 9,
                      y: 99.31,
                      extprop: 'flood'
                  }, {
                      x: 10,
                      y: 99.38,
                      extprop: 'power issue'
                  }, {
                      x: 11,
                      y: 99.20,
                      extprop: 'flood'
                  }, {
                      x: 12,
                      y: 99.38,
                      extprop: 'power issue'
                  }, {
                      x: 13,
                      y: 99.32,
                      extprop: 'flood'
                  }]
              },{
                    type: 'line',
                    marker: { enabled: false },
                    /* function returns data for trend-line */
                    data: (function() {
                      return fitData(sourceData).data;
                    })()
                }],
              credits: {
                  enabled: false
              }
          });

        });

    </script>

<body>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the link , i doing project on this , actually i having the 2 questions.

1.how to change the point color to the red which is below the trend line.
2.how to make the points and dates straight align i.e... the point is placing in between the dates.
3.when the page loads in the internet explorer 10 or 8 , the graph is not showing the animation effect like the graph plotting is with animation effect is loading in chrome and mozilla wher ie10,ie8 is now showing the animation effect. ?

This is the screen shot:

[image]

In the above graph the highlighted with circle change to red color point,
and second one is the line drawn to point to dates, which has to align straight to point.

please help.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry for the late reply, your both problems are solved with some minor modification, for all the red points, you need to specify their `color: 'red'`like:

```
{
   x: 11,
   y: 99.20,
   color: 'red',
   extprop: 'flood'
}
```

and the other problem was due to specifying xAxis Categories. So i put them outside and used the formatter to populate xAxis labels and also used `tickInterval: 1`

```
xAxis: {
    labels:{
        rotation: 90,
        align: "left",
        formatter: function () {
            return dates[this.value];
        },
    },
    tickInterval: 1
},
```

**[See the working DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/hj22wbe5/7/)**

Comment: thanks , i am doing the project in php , i am having the values and reason in the csv file while the data is coming from the csv so now i have to make the points red color which are plotting below the trend line.

Comment: the data is fetching from the csv and the value is below the trend line should show the point as a red color. and the values are fetching from the csv.

Comment: if you dont get .. please refer this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25686870/how-to-pass-the-another-variable-to-the-highchart-basic-line-which-should-be-dyn

Comment: come in the discussions section

Comment: please share the chat link

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60865/discussion-between-abdul-jabbar-and-john

Comment: i have one more question please help , when mouse over on the trend line the points are highlighting ...how to disable to points showing on the trend line when mouse over

Comment: Thanks,  is there any option to change the color of the trend line and graph

Comment: hi @abdul ,  why the animation effect is now appearing in the ie10 and ie8 when the graph loads

Comment: animation effect when page is loading the line will form like snake  according to the points , this effect is not supporting in the ie10, ie8

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60969/discussion-between-abdul-jabbar-and-john).

Comment: thanks and one more , when mouse over the reason is coming in the same line than how to make reason in new line in the tooltip

Comment: i added the <br> i got it

Comment: Hi abdul, is there  option to make the trend line z-index : -1000

Comment: because when mouse over on the graph sometimes the tool tip is not responding and also on the trend line mouse over is disable so is there any way to do the trend line z-index:-1000 zoom in

Comment: And tool tip ,  valueSuffix: '%',  is added in the tool tip the % is not coming after the value...?

Comment: HI abdul, how to show the % in tooltip after the value i.e.. in your code when i add the valueSuffix:'%' its getting the error...!

Comment: hi abdul , how to change the color of the graph which is in blue     base line graph

Comment: Hi abdul, i am trying to make to trend line as a dotted line ...by adding the css content in trend line code : border: 1px dotted #ff0000,  but the dotted line is not coming please suggest

Comment: Hi abdul, i am trying to make to trend line as a dotted line ...by adding the css content in trend line code : border-style: 'dotted', but the dotted line is not coming please suggest

Comment: you need to use dashstyle property of highcharts.. here: http://jsfiddle.net/hj22wbe5/15/

Comment: all the options available in highcharts can be found here.. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions   go through them thoroughly.

Comment: Thanks @abdul ...yes , i got it ..  and one more help is which library is useful for the bar graphs...

Comment: i personally used google charts Api and highcharts and after comparison with many other libraries i think highcharts is the best .. it can be a little tricky to understand because of huge amount of options but once you get it its fairly simple and feature rich.

Comment: yes , i choose this highcharts but new requirement by adding the trend line and tool tip with 3 options ..i am new to this things...and please provide which is the best chart library for the bar charts , is in highcharts bar charts is there ?

Comment: you really need to study this library inside out because you seem to have no information what so ever.. start from here: http://www.highcharts.com/demo   YES they have all sorts of charts including bar chart

Comment: oh, k thanks will start definitely thanks...if any doubts will ping...thanks very much

Comment: i found bar graph in this link :  http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic    is in 2D,  but in this graph is any there option to make the graph in 3D  like in excel having the graphs.